# singular perturbation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

I'm looking for literature pertaining to singulary perturbed fourth order parabolic equations. ex:$$u_{t}=-\epsilon u_{xxxx}+f(x,u)u_{xx}+g(x,u,u_x)$$ for sufficiently smooth functions $f,g$.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is "partaining"?

Comment: @Kaster It's almost certainly a trivial misspelling of "pertaining".

Comment: sorry, yes "pertaining" is the intended word.